# Spring Bean Dependency Does not Decide Construct Order

Tags: java, spring

When doing debugging with break points, I noticed that the order of execution of the `@Bean` annotated methods is not really related to their dependency relation. For e.g:

```
@Configuration
public class config {

    @Bean (name = "myDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {return new HikariDataSource();}


    @Bean
    public TransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new TransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {...}
}
```

The `transactionManager` or `sqlSessionFactory` method always gets run before the `dataSource()` method in my app. I made sure there's no data source auto config or any other code that might have created another data source.

And the app behavior is correct, it can connect to the correct DB and retrieve data.

This odd behavior might have something to do with multiple datasources. I configured more than 1 datasource in my app.

I know Spring has similar mechanism when dealing with cyclic dependencies. Say class A and B depends on each other, and when creating Bean A, A.b will be set to an empty instance of B. The same goes for B.

Here I'm assuming when running method `sqlSessionFactory()`, an empty dataSource will be created and passed to it. And that dataSource will later reference/proxy bean "myDataSource".

I want to know if my assumption is correct or if someone can explain the behavior clearly.

**Edit**

This is what my debug point looks like:
[image]

So the `transactionManager()` method always gets run first. And at this time, the injected `dataSource` (HikariDataSource) is still null.

But after the app starts and makes DB queries, it's using the correct dataSource:

[image]

My another dataSource is called orderDataSource and the mapper is referring it correctly.

I mean at last the `transactionManger` and `sqlSessionFactory` do use my specified dataSources, satisfying what my annotation demands, otherwise it would be a Spring bug and the app won't be able to function. But when the main thread is initializing those beans, the dataSource() method gets run last. I find it out in debugging mode. I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanism here.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. No proxy will be created or injected afterwards. The `DataSource` yuo get is the one being used. If that is a different one, then there must be another DataSource definition in your application which uses the same name and/or qualifier overriding this one. Also your latter one doesn't have the qualifier annotation so it will use the one which is `@Primary` or actually named `dataSource`.

Comment: From the debug above the injected `datasource` is not null, it is a wrapper for the `HikariDataSource`

Comment: @M.Deinum I have a bean name for the latter data source, just didn't show it here. I'm pretty sure there are no other data source beans because I disabled auto config and if I change my jdbc properties, the connection will fail. And I have my own property keys for jdbc config, so other data sources cannot use them be default.

Comment: @Azizi Yeah, but all the fields are null. I'm assuming it's just a placeholder at this point, and will be replace/filled when my own data source bean get initialized.

Comment: Spring does't use placholders, nothing will be filled after initiazation. There is something in your configuration that you haven't shown that is throwing things off.

Comment: Is your configuration marked as Lazy ?

Comment: @SKumar I didn't mark it lazy explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify a specific order, then you can use [@DependsOn](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on)

> We should use this annotation for specifying bean dependencies. **Spring guarantees that the defined beans will be initialized before attempting an initialization of the current bean.**

If you want `myDataSource` to be initialized first, define [@DependsOn({"myDataSource"})](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

```
@DependsOn({"myDataSource"})
@Bean
public TransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new TransactionManager(dataSource);
}

@DependsOn({"myDataSource"})
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {...}
```

> Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean

Comment: If you specify a qualifier spring is able to figure that out by itself already so no need for the `@DependsOn`.

Comment: @M.Deinum for some reason OP complains qualifier isn't preventing that `transactionManager` created before `myDataSource`

Comment: @DependsOn has the same result as the @Qualifier.  I mean at last the transactionManger and sqlSessionFactory do use myDataSource, satisfying what my annotation demands, otherwise it would be a Spring bug and the app won't be able to function. But when the main thread is initializing those beans, the `dataSource()` method get run last. I find it out in debugging mode. I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanism here.

Comment: @JFreebird static code may be executed before Spring bean initialization, is that the case?

Comment: I added more info in the post. There's no static code, just very typical @Configuration methods.

Comment: @JFreebird the code in your edit doesn't include `@DependsOn` or `@Qualifier`, also there no other DataSource ? also why method dataSource doesn't return `DataSource`?

Comment: I have a method returning `@Bean(name=orderDataSource)`, it's not in the screenshot though. I configed multiple data sources. But the @Qualifier or @DependsOn doesn't change anything. `HikariDataSource` implements `DataSource`

Answer (score 0):

> Here I'm assuming when running method sqlSessionFactory(), an empty dataSource will be created and passed to it. And that dataSource will later reference/proxy bean "myDataSource".
> I want to know if my assumption is correct or if someone can explain the behavior clearly.

In order to answer this question we need to look into the [bean creation lifecycle](https://reflectoring.io/spring-bean-lifecycle/)

[image]

Note that instantiation happens first, waaaaaay before everything else. This is where the `@Bean` annotated methods run.

Now its important to realise that Spring **not always** injects your dependencies directly, instead it **can** injects [proxies](https://ntsim.uk/posts/a-closer-look-at-spring-proxies), which wrap your beans. This is necessary to make some of Springs magic like `AOP` to work.

To see precisely what is being injected into your `@Bean` methods you can just set a debug breakpoint at these methods. Just using `toString()` won't work ... it will just tell you that its an ordinary object (proxy tries to hide that it's there lol ... )

If you investigate with the debugger, however ... you will see this ...

[image]

See ? There is no instance of object `A` being injected. A proxy is injected.

So, Spring does this in your case ... it creates these beans with `@Bean` methods and just gives each one a proxy of the dependency. Afterwards, since Spring has references to all the beans and proxies ... it wires them up together by figuring out the dependency graph via an algorithm similar to [topological sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/).

If something is still unclear, please leave a comment and I'll expand on it.

It would also help, if you could look in the debugger in the example above to see exactly what is being injected into your methods in place of the `DataSource` bean in both cases.

This will enable us to precisely pinpoint what's going on.

Comment: If there is no AOP there are also no proxies.  There are more thigns wrong with this answer.

Comment: Not at all. Proxies are always there. I'm just giving an example of how they are used.

Comment: @M.Deinum If you can specify concrete weakpoints in the answer, I can concretely address them.

Comment: No it isn't. Proxies are not always there, it might appear so but they aren't. Proxies are only there if there is AOP applicable to those beans, if not, no proxy will be injected. Also the bean will just be injected right then and there not later (unless explicity asked to do so with `@Lazy` or using an `ObjectProvider`). What you are showing in the debugger screenshot is the proxy of the `@Configuration` class **not** the proxy of the bean being created.

Comment: > What you are showing in the debugger screenshot is the proxy of the @Configuration class not the proxy of the bean being created.

But it is a proxy of class `A` which is an internal class of `Configuration` class .. therefore you get Config$A<HashId>

What is more ... there is no AOP added specifically to this class ... at least I did not do so manually ...

Comment: The actual class instance isn't a proxy it is just a plain instance. You are thrown off by the fact that you created it as an inner class of the `@Configuration` class for which, by dfeault, a proxy is always generated (unless you specify `proxyBeanMethods=false`). Also `Config$A` is actual the normal notation for an inner class not a proxy. You can try that without spring and aop and get the same result.

Comment: Touchey ! You are right !

Comment: I added more info in the original post. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @JFreebird I've taken a look at your screenshots from the debugger. We can clearly see that spring just injects a proxy into this object. This is evident from the class names. And later behind the scenes it will inject the real object into the proxy ( as we can see by the fact that the application works) 

If you want to know how spring proxies work read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html).

Does this answer your question to a degree that I can claim the bounty ? Or is this everything ?